# bitcoin-qt restored wallet.dat all synced closes after correct passphrase "assertion error crypt" HELP

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, backup, encryption, passphrase

Installed bitcoin-qt and replaced new wallet.dat with old wallet.dat backup

Opened bitcoin-qt and let it sync and all blocks synced and wallet has correct funds and past transactions.

I Want to send money from this wallet to new wallet not bitcoin-qt.

Bitcoin-qt asks for wallet password to send or recieve bitcoins.

I input correct password, bitcoin-qt closes!

**Following error on log** *= bitcoin-qt: crypter.cpp:189: bool
   CCryptoKeyStore::Unlock(const CKeyingMaterial&): Assertion `false'
   failed*

I know the password is the correct one. (Confirmed)

Other passwords give error. I've done -salvagewallet -rescan

**Update:**
I started bitcoind -daemon and did bitcoin-cli walletpassphrase "pass" 120 and gave me the exact same error as above.

Please help.

Comment: Do you have older backups of the same wallet you can try?

Comment: I only had that one copy of wallet.dat I did -rescan and -salvagewallet but when bitcoin-qt asks for password I input and it closes. and on the terminal shows the error in OP. Thanks